# How to fix "Not ImplementedError: call from another thread" in pypy

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, pypy

I am a beginner in Python.
When I run my code in pypy, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (process):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\Lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\Lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 218, in pre_process_event
    callback(event)
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())
  File "F:\my folders\programming\PycharmProjects\untitled1\Strategy.py", line 6055, in Hotkey_remove_1
    remove_1()
  File "F:\my folders\programming\PycharmProjects\untitled1\Strategy.py", line 4928, in remove_1
    calculate_Adad()
  File "F:\my folders\programming\PycharmProjects\untitled1\Strategy.py", line 4775, in calculate_Adad
    exec("Len_" + str(i) + "_Label.config(text=" + str(tedad) + ")")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1680, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1670, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
  File "F:\my folders\programming\pypy3.10-v7.3.12-win64\Lib\_tkinter\app.py", line 313, in call
    raise NotImplementedError("Call from another thread")
NotImplementedError: Call from another thread
```

How can I fix error?
OS: Windows
Python: 3.7
Pypy: 7.3.12

I read somewhere that the problem is with "tcl" and I tried to install the "tcl-thread" package, but I was unsuccessful.
If your answer is to install "tcl-thread" package, help me how to install it, please!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly related: https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/3822